# How to read a Byte array property in Jersey Web Service?

Tags: java, web-services, arrays, jersey

I currently have a byte array property in one of the entities in my Microsoft SQL Server. This property stores the byte array of images that I uploaded to the database. My Jersey restful web service running on netbeans has web services that are extracted from the database entities.

The byte array in the Microsoft SQL server starts with : 0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010201015301...

but the byte array that is displayed in the web service during a GET request starts with:
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEBUwFTAAD/4Qz8RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAA...

Obviously the webservice has changed the byte array through some means (that I am not sure of). How does a client of the web service use this string revert it back to the byte array format found in the Database? (I have tried using the Byte constructor and Byte.valueOf but both these methods give me a NumberFormatException)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is base64 encoded. So you have to use base64 decoder. Is your client Jersey-based?

Comment: yes it is. I found out later that the jersey client automatically encodes it with base 64